# Why selector is not getting called in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Can anyone please review the code written below and tell me why the tick method is never getting called.

```
-(void)okPressed
{

    CCLabelTTF *getReadyLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"GET READY"         fontName:@"BackBreaker.ttf" fontSize:30];
    [self addChild:getReadyLabel];
    getReadyLabel.position = ccp(_winSize.width/2,_winSize.height/2);
   [self schedule:@selector(tick:) interval: 0.1];

}

-(void)tick:(ccTime)dt
{
    CCLOG(@"dt=%f",dt);
}
```

When I run the code, getReadyLable is showing in the centre of the screen, but the tick method is never getting called. What is that I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you running the release configuration ?

Comment: does okPressed Method be call on click?

Comment: Yes, OkPressed method is getting called when I click the OK button.

Comment: I ran your code, and it works for me, I get 
-[GameTitle tick:] : dt=0.116484 and such numbers continually reading out in my log

Comment: so I think you must have made a mistake with calling okPressed, put a log in okPressed to double check it is being called, otherwise whoopty do, because the code works for me :D